# If/Then and Output Formatting in SQL Query

Tags: sql, mysql

Apologies for this being an extremely basic, near zero-knowledge questions.

There is a database that has 5 relevant fields.

- Field 1: Multivariable value
- Field 2: Multivariable value
- Field 3: Yes/No
- Field 4: Yes/No
- Field 5: Yes/No

Searches will be done in batches of 5-10 items.

Sample data would look something like...

```
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 |
| ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| Blah    | ABC     | No      | No      | No      |
| Widget  | XYZ     | Yes     | No      | No      |
| Doohick | 123     | Yes     | Yes     | Yes     |
```

Based on the Yes/No values of Field 3-5, one of four sentences needs to be outputted:

- Sentence 1 is whenever Field 3 is No
- Sentence 2 is Yes/No/No
- Sentence 3 is Yes/Yes/No
- Sentence 4 is Yes/Yes/Yes

Output data should look like this:

```
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Result                      |
| ------- | ------- | --------------------------- |
| Blah    | ABC     | Do a kickflip               |
| Widget  | XYZ     | Do a barrel roll            |
| Doohick | 123     | Doodydoodydoo               |
```

Not looking for somebody to write the query for me, just looking for advice on whether or not this is possible in purely with SQL.

(though if you want to write it, I won’t complain)

Comment: sample data and desired output will help us to help you

Comment: Sounds like a case expression is what is needed here, but I'm guessing a bit. What do you mean by the term "Sentence" in your question? Is `Field` the column of the table you are querying and `Result` the output of this sql? If you can edit your question and add three things *1)* Sample data *2)* desired results from that sample data using the logic you are outlined here *3)* update the tag with the RDBMS you are using (mysql, oracle, postgres, etc), then we can help craft this sql for you.

Comment: What happens when it's `yes/no/yes`?

Comment: Hopefully made some edits that help add clarity!

@JNevill, not a possible situation.

Answer (score 2):

I asked for more information in my comment, but I think I'm understanding enough to suggest a case expression in your SQL to output the sentence.

This would look something like:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
       WHEN Field3 = 'No' THEN 'Sentence 1' 
       WHEN Field4 = 'No' AND Field5 = 'No' THEN 'Sentence 2' 
       WHEN Field4 = 'Yes' AND Field5 = 'No' THEN 'Sentence 3'
       WHEN Field4 = 'Yes' AND Field5 = 'Yes' THEN 'Sentence 4'
       ELSE 'Condition not accounted for'
       END as result_field
FROM yourtable
```

This should catch every condition except for when `Field3` is `Yes` and `Field4` is `No` and `Field5` is `Yes` which is missing from your requirements, but it should illustrate how to write the logic. You can add conditions as needed.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it would be fairly straight forward, but my team is confused by the ask, even with an Excel-based proof of concept. I'm going to attempt to write it myself.